# Дистрибутив Python приложения

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller, scipy

У меня есть декстоп приложение, написанное на .Net. Вместе с ним мне необходимо упаковать еще одно приложение на Python. Есть ли способ, который позволит разрешить проблемы с зависимостям, чтобы моё приложение работало под любой Windows?
Я пробовал `pyinstaller` , но с его помощью получается упаковать приложение только под конкретную Windows. Была идея использовать портативный Python и архивы модулей, необходимых для работы приложения, но в зависимостях есть `numpy` и `scipy`, которым нужен компилятор, для сборки таким методом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло собрать бинарный файл с помощью `Pyinstaller` под 32 битной Windows 7. Проверил, полученное приложение запускается на Windows 7 (x86, x64), Windows 10 (x86, x64), Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Ну, я бы не спешил с утверждениями типа "запускается на любой Windows": например, чтобы на Windows XP запускалось (бывает такая необходимость до сих пор, к сожалению), нужно собирать на Python не новее версии 3.4.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, исправил.